# How to play many tracks via AVQueuePlayer in a row

Tags: ios, swift, avplayeritem, avqueueplayer

That is my first question and I did not find any answer about this issue.
I have a JSON with more than 2 thousand tracks on my server. And when I make an array of AVPlayerItem to insert into the AVQueuePlayer, It takes a lot of time. I want to load my tracks gradually.
Here is my code:

```
class Player: ObservableObject {
// Root link of my tracks
    private let link: String = "http://audio.radiohustle.online/"

// Link with my tracks on the server
    private let requestLink: String = "http://data.radiohustle.online/player/list/"
    
// AVQueuePlayer instance
    var queuePlayer: AVQueuePlayer?
    var playerItems: [AVPlayerItem] = []

// Function to make an array of AVPlayerItems and starting a Playback
    func makePlaylist() { to function
        AF.request(self.requestLink, method: .get).validate().responseDecodable(of: [Song].self) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                self.data = value.sorted(by: {$0.bpm < $1.bpm})
                self.test()
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

// Here is the Question
    func test() {
        guard let data = self.data else { return }
        
// Iteration and inserting all tracks from JSON to [AVPlayerItem]. It takes a lot of time to process 2000+ tracks
        for song in data {
            guard let songURL = URL(string: self.link + song.src) else {
                print("No songs")
                continue
            }
            self.playerItems.append(AVPlayerItem(url: songURL))
        }
        guard let playerItems = playerItems else { return }
        self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: self.playerItems)
        self.queuePlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

How to load tracks gradually, like in Apple Music App for example?

I was looking for information: Medium Tutorial with 4 parts, Youtube videos, tried to separate my array of tracks separating by smaller blocks. But it does not seem as a good approach.